# Laravel 5.7.8 Validation Errors not showing in contact view

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Using the latest `Laravel 5.7.8` and what worked in `Laravel 5.6.3` might not be applicable in my case.

I'm trying to create a Contact form validation (*required ALERT/SUCCESS messages*)

**contactUS.blade.php**

```html
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')


<div id="page">
 <div id="publish">
    <div class="frameterms">
<h1>Contact</h1>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
 
@if(Session::has('success'))
  <div class="notify yellow" style="display:block;">
     {{ Session::get('success') }}
   </div>
@endif
 

{!! Form::open(['route'=>'contactus.store']) !!}
<div class="row">
<label>Name<span class="asterix">*</span></label>
</div>
<div class="row {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">

{!! Form::text('name', old('name'), ['class'=>'row', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Name']) !!}
<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
</div>
 
<div class="row {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
  <label>Email<span class="asterix">*</span></label>
{!! Form::text('email', old('email'), ['class'=>'row', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Email']) !!}
<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
</div>
 

<div class="row {{ $errors->has('message') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
  <label>Subject<span class="asterix">*</span></label>
   <div class="selector">
   <div class="selector1">
   
  {!! Form::select('subject', array(
    'Select subject...' => 'Select subject...',
    'Web' => 'Web development',
    'Marketing' => 'Marketing',
    'App' => 'App development',
    'Advertising and Promotion' => 'Advertising and Promotion',
    'Other' => 'Other') ) !!}</div>
    <div>
  <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('message') }}</span>
  </div>


<div class="row {{ $errors->has('message') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
  <label>Message<span class="asterix">*</span></label>

{!! Form::textarea('message', old('message'), ['class'=>'row', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Message']) !!}
<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('message') }}</span>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <small class="required"><span class="asterix">*</span> Required fields</small>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('g-recaptcha-response') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  
   
  <div class="col-md-6 pull-center">
  {!! app('captcha')->display() !!}
  
  @if ($errors->has('g-recaptcha-response'))
  <span class="help-block">
  <strong>{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }}</strong>
  </span>
  @endif
  </div>
</div>

 
<div class="rowbutton">
  <input onclick="$('.loader').show(); $(this).hide();" type="submit" value="Send message">
  <div class="loader" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
 
{!! Form::close() !!}
 
</div>

</div>

</div>
</div>


@endsection
```

**ContactUSController.php**

```html
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\ContactUS;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Validator;
use Redirect;

 
class ContactUSController extends Controller
{
   /**
    * Show the application dashboard.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
   public function contactUS()
   {
       return view('pages.contactUS');
   }
 
   /**
    * Show the application dashboard.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
   public function contactUSPost(Request $request)
   {
       $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
        ]);
 
       ContactUS::create($request->all());
 
       return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
       return redirect()->back();
   }
}
```

**web.php**

```html
Route::get('contact', 'ContactUSController@contactUS');
Route::post('contact', ['as'=>'contactus.store','uses'=>'ContactUSController@contactUSPost']);
```

When I fill out the contact form, it adds a post to the SQL database on the backend. And when it fails, it goes back to the contact form view.

The problem is that the validator errors and SUCCESS message don't show up in the view even though I have coded in.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Is there any workaround? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

This is the picture from Laravel 5.6.3 project and required fields are working:

[image]

This is a picture from Laravel 5.7.8 project and required fields are NOT working:

[image]

Comment: can you try my answer?

Comment: As before, the message is created and sent but, the success cloud does not appear.

Comment: Did u tried my exact code? Bcz it's working fine on my side

Comment: Yes exact code! This code work on laravel 5.6. x but not on newer version 5.7.8   Maybe there is a problem in css? : S

Comment: Why the <div class="row"> do not change to <div class="row has-error"> ?

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your response as below.

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
```

Remove last return as well.

Comment: I try it but no success. Still the same.

Comment: In my previous project on laravel 5.6.3   the <div class="row"> turn to <div class="row has-error">   but here in laravel 5.7.8 stay the same  <div class="row">  in HTML inspection

Comment: Can you do this in blade file var_dump($errors); die();

Comment: How can I do that? Where exactly?

Comment: Add this to your blade file `<?php var_dump($errors); die() ?>` and refresh the page. You might get an error object there. let me know how that object so maybe I can help you.

Comment: I get this error: object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#232 (1) { ["bags":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: why its blank? Did you get this object after submitting your form ? or while you load your page where your form is located. we want an error object which you get after submitting a form.

Comment: If I copy this at the top I have the blank page. If I copy to the bottom I have the form without CSS. But also I get this error: object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#232 (1) { ["bags":protected]=> array(0) { } }     NO OTHER ERROR OBJECTS

Answer (score 0):

After  ContactUS::create($request->all()) line you can use
This is my code

```
    Session::flash('successMsg','what ever you want to message');

    @if( Session::has('successMsg'))
      <p class="btn btn-block btn-success disabled successMsg m-b-30">{{ 
         Session::get('successMsg') }}</p>
    @endif
```

make validation like this. USe validator in top.
    use Validator;

make a validation array which $request you want to verify. Then make verify like this. In else section you write your code . and in if section give a valid message.

```
$v = [
        'image' => 'image|mimes:png,ico|max:200',
    ];
    $validator  = Validator::make($request->all(),$v);
    if($validator->fails()){
        Session::flash('errorMsg',$validator->errors());
        return redirect()->back();
    }else{

     }
```

Comment: I try it but no success. Still the same.

Comment: Now see how I flash session and get it from font end. You need to
    use Session; 
this in top

Comment: Now I get error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Session' not found. Problem is here: Session::flash('successMsg','what ever you want to message');

Comment: Did you use Session in your controller. 
 
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\ContactUS;

just like these add 

   use Session;

Comment: No I didn't. You mean App\Session;    like this? To add at the top?

Comment: yap. add   "use Session" . No need to add App

Comment: I try it. Now I get only blank white page.

Comment: I also try to edit  class="btn btn-block btn-success disabled successMsg m-b-30" but nothing in return then.

Comment: are you sure about your validation is ok or not. Cause you are using validate function if it fails then it directly return to back with out any message.

Comment: No I am not sure. How to check this?

Comment: What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the `view` route where you want to show the message like:

```
return redirect('contact')->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
```

And then in your `blade` view get it like:

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Ref: [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

**UPDATE:**

From your this comment `Why the <div class="row"> do not change to <div class="row has-error"> ?` it seems you are talking about `$errors` so what you need to do is check whether error messages exists or not and after that display it like below:

If you want to display error under each field you can do like this.

```
@if ($errors->has('firstname'))
    <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('firstname') }}</div>
@endif
```

In new version of laravel it is changed to something like `if ($errors->any())` However you can refer to docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).

Comment: We are talking about errors (required fields) and also success messages after successfully send the email.   All code above work in 5.6 but not in 5.7

Comment: What error are you getting now? You're not clear with your comments!

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But it seems that also doesn't work. I don't get any alert (required fields) and also no success massage.

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel 5.7 [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

```
  return redirect('contact')->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
```

After the user is redirected, you may display the flashed message from the session. For example, using Blade syntax:

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: As before, the message is created and sent but, the success cloud does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want to get an error for required fields you must put it like this:

{!! Form::text('name', old('name'), ['class'=>'row', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Name','required']) !!}

The key is 'required'  and not like required without ''.
I still didn't figure it out how to, do success message properly.